# copy elision and rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
   A (){}

    A(const A&)
    {
        std::cout << "copy" << "\n";
    }

    A& operator =(A)
    {
        return *this;
    }
}; 

int main()
{ 
    A  a;
    A a2;

    a=std::move(a2);

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 1;
}
```

It seems that the rule for copy elision is that the argument must be an prvalue and not a xvalue but why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems that the rule for copy ellision is that the argument must be an prvalue and not a xvalue but why?

Your program does not contain a situation where copy/move elision can be performed. The C++11 Standard specifies exactly these situations in Paragraph 12.8/31:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects. [...]
>   **This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances** (which
>   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> — in a return statement in a function with a class return type, **when the expression is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object** (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified
>   type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>   the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

This is not your situation, because the expression `return`ed by your `operator =` is `*this`, which is not the name of an object with automatic storage duration. Moreover, you are not storing the result of `operator =` anyway.

> — in a throw-expression, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a
>   function or catch-clause parameter) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost
>   enclosing try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from the operand to the exception
>   object (15.1) can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the exception object

This does not apply, because you have no `throw` expression.

> — when a **temporary** class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>   to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

This does not apply either, because you have no temporaries (an *xvalue* is not a temporary).

> — when the exception-declaration of an exception handler (Clause 15) declares an object of the same type
>   (except for cv-qualification) as the exception object (15.1), the copy/move operation can be omitted
>   by treating the exception-declaration as an alias for the exception object if the meaning of the program
>   will be unchanged except for the execution of constructors and destructors for the object declared by
>   the exception-declaration.

There is no exception handler in your code, so this situation does not apply either.

---

If your intended question is "*Why are things the way they are?*", there is no objective, exhaustive answer that I am able to provide (though others might). But I will try to bring on some plausible arguments.

As specified by the paragraph of the Standard quoted above, copy elision in the case of a `return` statement means that the function is allowed to construct the object being returned directly into the assigned object.

Concretely, this means that the compiler will probably produce code for that function that works directly on the object to which the return value is to be assigned, and that lives *outside* of the invoked function's stack frame, rather than on a local object with automatic storage duration allocated *inside* the function's stack frame. This means you can see the local object as an alias for the assigned one.

However, here you have *two* very distinct objects, both materially constructed, both of which require memory and live at two different addresses. There is no way to apply a trick similar to the one outlined previously, because that kind of aliasing would require changing the address of an object during a program's execution - and that's illegal.